# Substitute and store in another scalar

Tags: regex, perl

How can I use $_ to store my string, and then use another scalar variable to store the substituted string such that I have both the copies. Do we have a modifier to copy the default argument in some another variable?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl/
use warnings;
use strict;

$_ = "X is a good boy. X works daily and goes to school. X studies for 12 hours daily \n";

s/X/Sam/g;
print $_, "\n";
```

What I want in the end is the original $_ and the substituted string as well.

Edit: I used

```
my $new = s/X/Sam/gr
```

But I get an error related to build, and it doesnt solve the issue. I am using version 5.10.1

```
perl --version

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Comment: `(my $new = $_)=~s/X/Sam/g;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way, of course, is to first copy the original and make the substitution on the copy.

```
( my $new = $_ ) =~ s/X/Sam/g;
```

Another way is to use the `/r` modifier (introduced in v5.14). It returns the new string, leaving the original unchanged

```
my $new = $_ =~ s/X/Sam/gr;
```

Find it [in  perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators), under the bullet "*s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer*".

Note interesting uses in Examples. With `/r` you can also do

```
my $new = s/X/Sam/gr;
```

---

Since `/r` modifier is available on v5.14 or newer you may want to have `use 5.014;`, not allowing the code to run at all on older Perls and documenting the required version. On the other hand, without that on an older Perl you *get a specific error*, with the location where unavailable features are used.

Comment: aka, add: `use 5.016;` :)

Comment: @jm666 Thank you -- added.

Comment: I am not getting the desired output after your solution. Probably some mistake on my side. I am getting the following error: Bareword found where operator expected at reg_expressions.pl line 7, near "s/X/Sam/gr"
syntax error at reg_expressions.pl line 7, near "s/X/Sam/gr"
Execution of reg_expressions.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @ShankhadeepMukerji Comes to mind ... is your Perl older than v5.16? If so, there is no `/r` (and you'd get the error like what you report).  In that case you have to copy the variable first, `my $var = $_;` and then run the regex (without that `/r`) on `$var` (or on `$_` and keep `$var` unchanged).  If you have v5.16 or later then it looks like a syntax error.

Comment: @jm666 [It's 5.014](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution)

Comment: Re "*It is still good to have `use 5.014;`*", That's debatable. Some people don't like that vagueness of `use 5.014;` and rather see the failures so they can be addressed if necessary. As far as I'm concerned, the installer will already enforce a min version.

Comment: @ikegami Thank you very much for the edits.  Personally, I'd rather get hit by the actual error.  But I thought that it may be considered a "good practice" to spell out needed versions -- thanks for the comment (that it's not clear).  I will edit that statement.

Answer (score 1):

I try as much as possible not to use $_ for anything other then casting it to another variable. I have had problems, that in complex looping $_ gets lost.
Its four lines of code and so maybe not particularly eloquent, but...

```
$orig = $_;
$changed = $_;
$changed = s/X/Sam/g;
print "CHANGED: ".$changed."\bORIGINAL: ".$orig\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following if you need compatibility with versions of Perl older than 5.14:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl/
use warnings;
use strict;

$_ = "X is a good boy. X works daily and goes to school. X studies for 12 hours daily \n";
my $m;
($m = $_)=~s/X/Sam/g;
print $m, "\n";
```

Here, `$m` stores the modified data, and `$_` remains unchanged.